# Does bugsense crash handler need to be called in each activities of an Android application?

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, bug-tracking, bugsense

My app has 3 activities A,B and C.
From A (the "home") i can start B and from B i can start C.

Do i have to call `BugSenseHandler.setup(this, MY_API_KEY);` only in A or also in B and C?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After contacting BugSense,

> Android, Feb 26 13:42 (EET): Hello and thank you for contacting us,
>   you can place it either on the application activity, or on the first
>   activity that runs on your project. In the documentation we suggest
>   the second practice, since it's easier and quicker for the majority of
>   the developers.
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  BugSense

As for me, I've been placing it on the Application Activity and it has been working fine.

Answer (score 11):

I've used it in several app by calling it in the onCreate of Application object (mainly so it'll catchup any errors in the app initialisation. It's also worth noting as of v3 of the jar i believe the `setup` method is remove and now use `initAndStartSession`

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, BUG_SENSE_API_KEY);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to call setup only on A Activity.